# How to route from AngularJS page to a page running using ReactJS in two different ports

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I have an application which has a landing page developed using AngularJS. The login screen is developed using AngularJS and when the user logs in, the token should be saved in local storage and go to the landing page.In that Landing page there is a button. When I press that button the page should route to a page which is developed using ReactJS which runs on a different server running in a different port . 
(Eg. React app in port 3000 and Angular port is 4000)

When the page is redirected to the ReactJS page, that page should be able to access that user token which we previously saved in local storage . Also I want to know the security aspect of saving the token in local storage and is there any other alternatives to do that.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. not sure if this will suffice as an answer, but why do you want it to run on two separate ports? I have worked on such a project and in my case it was like this..

MYAPP/landing   - developed in angular

MYAPP/dashboard - developed in react

so, basically I have the React prod build in one of my subdirectories and the Angular prod build in the rootDirectory and had configured in my server config files to handle the requests accordingly(I used apache websever)..

Comment: We need several ports as these are several web applications. The user first logins to the main portal and then can click on links to which application he wants to go. Some applications are written in Angular some are ReactJS but in different ports.